# INNER JOIN unique column mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, inner-join

I have planned to use three tables for my sites tagging system, they looks like:

```
|-----------------------|
|==> photo              |
|   -> id               |
|   -> custom_id        |
|   -> title            |
|   -> slug             |
|   -> date             |
|   -> image_url        |
|-----------------------|
|==> tags               |
|   -> id               |
|   -> slug             |
|   -> title            |
|-----------------------|
|==> tags_relation      |
|   -> tid              | <-- this is the tags.id
|   -> pid              | <-- this is the photo.custom_id
|-----------------------|
```

So, to fetch the recent posts of a specific tag i am using INNER JOIN by the following query:

```
        SELECT p.id, p.custom_id, p.title, p.slug, p.date, p.image_url, t.id, t.slug, tr.* 
        FROM tags t INNER JOIN
            tags_relation tr
            ON t.id = tr.tid INNER JOIN
            photo p
            ON p.custom_id = tr.pid
        WHERE t.slug = 'people' 
        ORDER BY p.date DESC 
        LIMIT 20
```

Everything works fine except the fact that the 'slug, id, title' column of the photo table is being replaced by the 'slug, id, title' column of the tags table!
I figured out a solution that is changing the tags columns name, but is there any best practices to solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should use Aliases.
For example:

```
SELECT p.id AS Person_Id, p.title AS Person_Title ...
```

You can learn more about aliases [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to cast some of those fields like this

```
SELECT t.column, s.column AS column2
```

Otherwise, MySQL will indeed pick a field to return (typically the last one with that name) and that's all you get!

Answer (score 0):

Our best practice may seem like more work, but we do add unique prefixes to all our column names so you don't get lost in an alias war.

```
|-----------------------|
|==> photo              |
|   -> photo_id         |
|   -> photo_custom_id  |
|   -> photo_title      |
|   -> photo_slug       |
|   -> photo_date       |
|   -> photo_image_url  |
|-----------------------|
|==> tags               |
|   -> tag_id           |
|   -> tag_slug         |
|   -> tag_title        |
|-----------------------|
|==> tags_relation      |
|   -> tagRelation_tid  | 
|   -> tagRelation_pid  | 
|-----------------------|
```

Which would change your query to

```
SELECT photo_id, photo_custom_id, photo_title, photo_slug, photo_date, photo_image_url, tag_id, tag_slug, tags_relation.* 
    FROM tags INNER JOIN
        tags_relation             
        ON tag_id = tagRelation_tid INNER JOIN
        photo
        ON photo_custom_id = tagRelation_pid
    WHERE tag_slug = 'people' 
    ORDER BY photo_date DESC 
    LIMIT 20
```

More verbose, but also more descriptive and when you have many many tables and really really long joins, it works out great...especially when your intellisense kicks in.

Comment: It works but it is not very nice. Take "tag_id" for example. You already have table's name "tag" to indicate the id is a tag's id. Specifying second time the "tag" part is too much. It works of course but it is not elegant. It's like saying, "This red apple has red colour!". I wouldn't recommend getting used to use practices like this.

Comment: it's all about scale...when you deal with aliases everywhere it can get funky...the table's name is 'tags', btw...not 'tag'...there is a difference

Comment: Yeah ok the table's name is 'tags'. What about table 'photo'? And I understand what you're saying. You are right. But your time is better spent designing your database better than trying to patch workarounds allover the place. Don't get me wrong. What you said is an acceptable solution. I just do not think it is elegant.

Comment: yeah my db design is not so good but i am thinking of adding table name as columns prefix though its going to be a choppy idea for my platform.

Comment: just wait till you start implementing an ORM